# "recvfrom" from pythons "socket" library cant find message successfully sent over ethernet cable in UDP implementation

Tags: python, sockets, udp, wireshark, ethernet

Im trying to implement UDP where a python script on my computer is running the server and a microcontroller connected by ethernet cable is running a client. In the python script i bind to the ip of the ethernet port and a port nr, and in wireshark i can see that the destination ip and port nr of the messages arriving from the client are the same as those bound to in the python script. But when i run the script it gets stuck in recvfrom and finds nothing, dispite continuous messages being sent to the port the socket is bound to. Any help or ideas are greatly appreciated!

the python script in question:

```
import socket

localIP     = "192.168.1.123"

localPort   = 12345

bufferSize  = 1024

msgFromServer  = "Hello UDP Client"

bytesToSend    = str.encode(msgFromServer)

# Create a datagram socket

UDPServerSocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# Bind to address and ip

UDPServerSocket.bind((localIP, localPort))

print("UDP server up and listening")

# Listen for incoming datagrams

while(True):

    bytesAddressPair = UDPServerSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)

    message = bytesAddressPair[0]

    address = bytesAddressPair[1]

    # Sending a reply to client

    UDPServerSocket.sendto(bytesToSend, address)
```

Comment: Your script works for me. How do you know that _the script it gets stuck in recvfrom and finds nothing_? Are you sure that the `localIP` is correct?

Comment: I know it gets stuck in recv because i have a print before and after, and it doesnt reach the one after (removed the prints for clarity). Im fairly certain the ip is correct, i can see it wireshark and i set it manually. Also python complains when you bind to an ip they cant find.

Comment: The code looks okay to me. Is the microcontroller sending to 192.168.1.123? What is the microcontroller's IP address? Is the microcontroller plugged into your main home network? If you have a *separate* network between the microcontroller and the computer, normally that network would have IP addresses starting with something else, e.g. 192.168.2, to avoid conflicts.

Comment: Yes the The microcontroller is sending to 192.168.1.123, i can see that in wireshark. The microcontroller is connected to an ethernet port with a static ip of 192.168.1.123. The microcontrollers ip is 192.168.1.111, could that be an issue?

Comment: @CasparWesterberg which IP address does your computer use for wi-fi?

Comment: the ip for wifi starts with 192.168.3

Comment: @CasparWesterberg `192.168.1.xxx` and `192.168.3.xxx` are on different networks

Comment: @RemyLebeau but does the ip for wifi matter if im using ethernet? I set the ip for my ethernet socket to 192.168.1.123 and the ip of the controller to 192.168.1.111, should these be on the same network as wifi? The script is listening to the 192.168.1 network

Comment: @user253751 does the ip for wifi matter if im using ethernet?

Comment: @CasparWesterberg It matters because the whole 192.168.1 is your wi-fi network and your computer is probably trying to send the response over wi-fi, because it has an address that matches your wi-fi network, or perhaps it's ignoring the packet from the microcontroller, because it has an address that matches your wi-fi network but it didn't come on wi-fi. Try using 192.168.2 for your microcontroller network.

Comment: @user253751 are you sure? wifi is on network 192.168.3, does that conflict with having ethernet socket on 192.168.1? But not on 192.168.2? (it would be some work to change as im not admin of this computer)

Comment: @CasparWesterberg oh that wouldn't be a problem. I read wrong, and I thought they were both 192.168.1

Answer (score 0):

Found it! My firewall was blocking the python script from seeing the udp package, so i will try to turn of the firewall for the specific port.
Thank you @Zac67